# Setting content type in Jena RDFConnection Header

Tags: java, sparql, jena, triplestore

I need to modify the header (specifically the Content-Type) of a request (eg: update) of an RDFConnection object in a Jena transaction. More precisely,  I need to add the following Header Content_Type
`Content-Type = [application/sparql-query; charset=UTF-8]`

in the following code

```
try (RDFConnection conn = connectionFactory.create()) {
  Txn.executeWrite(conn, () -> {
    conn.update(updateRequest);// HERE we want to setup the Content-Type in the header
  });
}catch (Exception e) {... }
```

I have setup the connectionFactory as follow

```
public RDFConnection create() {
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
    return
        RDFConnectionRemote.create()
        .destination(endpointURL)
        .queryEndpoint("query")
        .updateEndpoint("update")
        .httpClient(httpClient)
        .parseCheckSPARQL(true)
        .build();
  }
```

So, I still need to specify the charset of the request body in the the request header content-Type . How can I do that with JENA ?

Note: the default JENA RDFConnection setting is not sufficient because the remote endpoint still needs the explicit specification of the charset to parse my SPARQL requests containing French accents in the URIs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SPARQL update strings are defined for UTF-8 (only). If the endpoint isn't honouring that, it's a bug although make sure the updateRequest string is UTF-8 (e.g. if it is read from a file on Windows, it may not be). What is the server endpoint running?

Comment: Apache Jena has switched (at 4.3) to using the JDK java.net.http code - your example uses  Apache HttpComponents.

Comment: @Andys thanks for the quick feedback.
I am using the free version of stardog triplestore.

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5820/datasetTest/query'\
--header 'Origin: https://stardog.studio/'\
--header 'Content type: application/sparql-query; charset=UTF-8'\
--data-raw 'select distinct * where { graph ?g { <https://myTest.com/ontologies#Régime_Alimentaire> ?x ?y }}'`

This query returns the expected results. However if I remove the Content-Type or the charset=UTF-8, the query will return empty.

Comment: @Andys, I just found a report in the Stardog community for the same issue where the user had to specify the Header Content-Type to charset=UTF-8 when using rdflib (python) to query Stardog (https: //community.stardog. com/t/python3-8-rdflib-utf-8-problems-sparqlstore/3394)
Since this bug seems to be recurring with some Triplestores, is there a way to access the Content-Type parameter in Jena RDFConnection ? Thanks :)

Comment: The curl request has a bad header : "Content type:" (no "-"), and it is a query not an update. Sorry - these details matter. If there is no Content-type at all then it is not a SPARQL query at all. If the query does not match, then it is still open as to whether the update inserted bad or the query does not transmit correctly or maybe stardog tries autodetect if there is no forcing charset. As asked on the Jena ticket what OS are you using?

Comment: It is not "some triplestores" - you are saying it is one triplestore. It isn't practical for every client toolkit to code for each vendors triplestore. The answer gives you a way for Jena 4.3.2 with the new highly configurable query and update execution builders. Indeed you can modify the details of any request -- see  https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sparql-apis/#changes. There may be a way in older Jena (QueryEngineHTTP) or with the Apache HttpClient builder setDefaultHeaders. But 4.3.2 has a uniform treatment or connections and it is wise to upgrade for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Jena 4.3.2 has a uniform interface with detailed control of HTTP requests.

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sparql-apis/#changes

For SPARQL update `UpdateExecutionHTTP.newBuilder()` and SPARQL query `QueryExecutionHTTP.newBuilder()`, there is a builder operation for setting any HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you @Andys for the feedback and response.
Yes we agree that it is mainly a STARDOG bug (I added it in the tags).
Indeed the JENA UpdateExecHTTP allows access to the configuration of the headers on the other hand, unless I am mistaken (?), this system is not transactional unlike the RDFConnection.

Comment: we will mark this as the accepted answer. We are still using Jena 3.x in most parts. We started upgrading to 4.2 slowly. The reason is we were stuck with centos servers with only Java8 built in. Since the great centos change, we moved to other OS + java 11. Some code are still using the old Jena.

Comment: RDFConnection is not transactional to the server so nothing is lost. The transaction of RDFConnection is local/client-side isolation. A SPARQL Update operation is defined as atomic, usually systems encapsulate in a transaction at the server.  So using UpdateExecutionHTTP and the general SPARQL protocol is no lost of functionality. It is the server responsibility to execute atomically.

Comment: @mahery-rafara  You could build from source after changing the constant. A release is source code with convenience binaries going to maven central. But Java8 is now getting a little old (security) and Java11 is faster.